# Jquery Ajax data with letters "rc" not sending to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is by FAR the weirdest issue I have ever come across. I am completely baffled as the code is PERFECT. I've tested a hundred different things and it came down to something between the ajax post to the php file.

The "logged_lg" input is the username. Every login works except logins starting with "rc". Coincidently enough my real name initials are "rcs", so you can see how I ran into this. I thought it was due to my multiple accounts on my platform at first, but I deleted them all and not one account even has "rc" within it. I will reiterate that only the starting letters "rc" or "RC" or "rC" etc, make this function not go through. The beforesend function continuously shows the loader.

Please keep in mine I am not posting all of the code for obvious reasons.

```
var formData = {
    'ldata' : $('input[name=logged_lg]').val(),
    'password' : $('input[name=password]').val()
};
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use
        url : '/log-in/logchk.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data : formData, // our data object
        dataType : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode : true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".form_info .error").hide();
            $(".form_info").show();
            $(".form_info .loader").show();
        }
}
```

This is from the PHP file.

```
$lgfroto =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ldata']);
$hdmain_lg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Even when I replaced the lgfroto value with "anytext" as a user, logging in worked. I also have error handlers that work, and I tried.

```
if ($lgfroto == "rc"){
    $errors['email'] = 'is rc.';
}
```

I typed in rc to the input field to see if it would pass, but it doesn't get passed the beforesend function. Any other characters worked.

Here is some(important part) of the form code, which I can't see what would be wrong, but just so you can see.

```
<form id="form" action="/log-in/logchk.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="email-group">
<div class="input_row">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="Username or Email" name="logged_lg" class="input_text idleField">
</div>
</div>
<div id="pw-group">
<div class="input_row pw_it">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="Password" name="password" class="input_text idleField pw_it">
</div>
```

Comment: And what's the `encode` option in `$.ajax` for ?

Comment: Also, you need to attach a `done` and `fail` function to the ajax call, and console log the results, to see why the request isn't sent

Comment: So did you look at what is being sent to the server in the network tab in your developer console? Did you look at the response?

Comment: I realize that, but you should add some handlers to see why it doesn't work with `rc`, there's probably a good reason

Comment: @epascarello - logchk.php (failed) xhr jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 0 B 182 ms. - Is this a jquery issue?

Comment: So did you look at the request and response tabs in the network tab? Does the request have the right data, does the response have the error message from php?

Comment: Besides what I pasted, there is...POST http://fakedomainforu.com/log-in/logchk.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - obviously fakedomain is a fake name

Comment: Do this, and tell us what you get -> **https://jsfiddle.net/0omhf6nh/**

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

For anyone running into passing issues. Jquery doesn't like to pass the variable name 'ldata' for some messed up reason, and there are no docs on this.

```
'ldata' : $('input[name=logged_lg]').val(),
'password' : $('input[name=password]').val()
```

Every other variable name works just fine. Totally bonkers.